# How to automatically update the expired status on contracts when they expire? Spring boot

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-thymeleaf

My company just started using contracts. I created a value in the Status picklist called Expired for expired contracts. My goal is to automate the setting of the value to Expired without asking the sales people to do it. My company just started using contracts. I created a value in the Status picklist called Expired for expired contracts. My goal is to automate the setting of the value to Expired without asking the sales people to do it.

I use Spring boot and Thymeleaf.

I have done several searches on the internet but I can't find a solution. Could someone help me find a suitable solution.

I use Spring boot, Thymeleaf and MySql as my Database Management System.

Comment: The best way you can do this in my personal opinion is with a database scheduled job.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your various interventions.
How could I create a scheduled task in the database that will automatically change the status to expired if the end date is equal to the machine's local date.

Comment: Ok my code is in french